# How to file a bug on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, printing

There is a cups problem and I don't know how or where I could submit a bug report.

Comment: There's an IRC Channels for Ubuntu, Open [this](http://webchat.freenode.net/) and join a channel, see [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList) for a list of **Official** Ubuntu IRC Channels, those might help you.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug not a misconfiguration? See the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) on when and how to report bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite alot of packages include information about who maintains them and where to file bugs - you can view this information for a package by running `sudo apt-cache show PACKAGENAME` - so for `cups` (on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)

```
$ apt-cache show cups
Package: cups
...
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-di...
Original-Maintainer: Debian Printing Team <debian-printi...
...
Homepage: http://www.cups.org
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
....
```

<sup>Emails removed - find them and the bug URLs by running the `apt-cache ...` command</sup>

So you should be able to file a bug at the given URL, or you could even email the maintainer of the package (filing a bug would likely be better). However, please check and verify whether this a bug, and not a problem with another package, misconfiguration, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Bug reports can be submitted using the **apport-bug** application from a terminal.

Open a terminal and use the command `apport-bug package_name` and press enter.

In your case, for cups you would use :

```
apport-bug cups
```

For more options and instructions you can read the apport-bug man page using :

```
man apport-bug
```